# Update on Scheduler Task in Extbase 6.2

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.x

I am new to Extbase and my mindset is still database driven. I've created a extension and added a scheduler task. Now I want to use the scheduler task to update a relation.

The record has UID 1 in \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\OriginalRepository
And I want to setIdendify to \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Identify

What I already did is, I've create the new Identify Object like this:

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$repository = $objectManager->get('Vendor\\Extension\\Domain\\Repository\\IdentifyRepository');

$new = new \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Identify;
$new->setName('test');

$repository->add($new);
```

But how can add this now to \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\OriginalRepository?

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you use a [CommandController](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_controller_1_1_command_controller.html) for implementing your scheduler tasks, you can use dependency injection. Makes initializing stuff easier. Also, you should use `ObjectManager::get()` to create a new `Identify`-instance - that way lifecycle methods are called.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but I guess you could just create an instance of `OriginalRepository`, use `findByUid()` to get your instance of `Original`, modify it, and persist the change using the `update()` method of the `OriginalRepository`-instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried it like this:
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$repository = $objectManager->get('Vendor\\Extension\\Domain\\Repository\\OriginalRepository');
$repository->findByUid($row['uid']);
$repository->setIdentify($new);
$repository->update($query);

Comment: But I get an error: The method "setIdentify" is not supported by the repository.

Comment: Um, I think you should read a bit about the concepts behind extbase, what a domain object is, what a repository is for and so on. You probably need to call `setIdentify()` on the result returned by `$repository->findByUid()`.